# node.js does not load javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a total newbie to node.js.

My problem is that the html-file 'index.html' called as 'localhost:5000' seems not to load the javascript file 'test.js'.

I start the server by

nodejs server.js

from a shell. The files are

server.js:

```
var http = require('http');
const process = require('process'); 
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    if (request.url === "/") {
        fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, pgResp) {
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Page is not found');
            } else {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.write(pgResp);
            }

            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.write('<h1>Default Content</h1>');
        response.end();
    }});
server.listen(5000);
console.log('Server is listening on 5000');
console.log(process.cwd())
```

The path process.cwd() is the path of the three files server.js, index.html and test.js

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <center>
    <h2>Testing NodeJS Application </h2>
    <p> This is my first web application using NodeJS </p>
    </center>
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="test.js"></script>
    <script>
      alert('Even this is a Test!');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and test.js:

```
alert('I am here!');
```

The alert in index.html is shown, the alert in test.js is not.

I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: you might need to serve static files https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the way you are importing the **test.js** script in your HTML file:

```html
    <script  type="text/javascript"  src="test.js"></script>
```

This file is being loaded on your browser, but the route provided in `src=` can't be resolved since `"test.js"` is not a valid URL or route to the file where you can load it from.

You should first define where are you going to expose your `"test.js"` file from, so it can be fetched from your browser, and then, correct the value in `src=` to the actual URL.

For example, a common practice is exposing public files in a `/public/` folder in your server code, then expose the files in there when the URL matches such `/public/**some-file.js` pattern.

In your code you can achieve that by doing:

```js
//...
var path = require('path');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    if (request.url.startsWith("/public/")) {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, path.normalize(req.url)), function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err));            
            return;
          }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });

      return;
    }

    if (request.url === "/") {
       // ...      
    } else {
       // ...
    }});

//... rest of your code
```

You can find more details in this guide: [How to serve static files](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/).

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I use. I placed the javascript file test.js in a folder named public.

```
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var static = require('node-static');
const process = require('process'); 
var fs = require('fs');


var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    if (request.url.startsWith("/public/")) {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, path.normalize(request.url)), function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end(JSON.stringify(err));            
            return;
          }
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(data);
      });

      return;
    }

    if (request.url === "/") {
        fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, pgResp) {
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Page is not found');
            } else {
                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                response.write(pgResp);
            }

            response.end();
        });
    } else {

        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        response.write('<h1>Default Content</h1>');
        response.end();
    }
});

server.listen(5000);

console.log('Server is listening on 5000');
console.log(process.cwd())
```

Many thanks!!!!